# Django not finding command when importing CSV data with Dictreader

Tags: python, django

I would like to use Python's Dictreader to import a csv file based on my Django model into the database.

My post model is:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
            ("draft", "Draft"),
            ("published", "Published")
    );

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250);

    wine_id = models.IntegerField();
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100);
    description = models.TextField();
    designation = models.TextField();
    price = models.FloatField();
    province = models.CharField(max_length=100);
    region_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100);
    region_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100);
    variety = models.CharField(max_length=100);
    winery = models.CharField(max_length=100);

    objects = models.Manager();

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("id",);

    def __str__(self):
        return self.variety;

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_detail", args=[self.id,
                                            self.province,
                                            self.slug]);
```

My script to read the csv data is:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    # Shows this when the user types help:
    help = "Loads data from wine_data.csv into our Post model.";

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if Post.objects.exists():
            print("Wine data already loaded... exiting...");
            print(ALREADY_LOADED_ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;

        print("Loading wine data for WCC.");
        for row in DictReader(open("wine_data.csv")):
            post = Post();
            post.wine_id = row["wine_id"];
            post.country = row["country"];
            post.description = row["description"];
            post.designation = row["designation"];
            post.price = row["price"];
            post.province = row["province"];
            post.region_1 = row["region_1"];
            post.region_2 = row["region_2"];
            post.variety = row["variety"];
            post.winery = row["winery"];
            post.save();
```

However, when I use "python manage.py load_wine_data", the cmd says it is an unknown command. What am I doing wrong and how can I solve it?

Comment: Is the script called `load_wine_data.py`? Is it in a `management/commands` directory, inside an installed app?

Comment: No. Is it compulsory to be?

Comment: Yes. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/): "just add a management/commands directory to the application. Django will register a manage.py command for each Python module in that directory whose name doesn’t begin with an underscore".